# Image Checkbox List is not work properly

Tags: image, list, checkbox

Please Look at the URL:  http://www.supereleman.com/test/2.html

When ı click the text, checkbox is selected. But (reverse of this) when ı clicked to image, text and image have not been clicked..

What must ı do for when ı clicked to image, checkbox is selected?

My code;

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="custom-form-elements.js"></script>

<style>
.multiselect {
width:10em;
height:5em;
border:solid 1px #c0c0c0;
overflow:auto;
}

.multiselect label {
display:block;
}

.multiselect-on {
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#3399ff;
}
</style>
<link href="form.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script>
jQuery.fn.multiselect = function() {
$(this).each(function() {
    var checkboxes = $(this).find("input:checkbox");
    checkboxes.each(function() {
        var checkbox = $(this);
        // Highlight pre-selected checkboxes
        if (checkbox.attr("checked"))
            checkbox.parent().addClass("multiselect-on");

        // Highlight checkboxes that the user selects
        checkbox.click(function() {
            if (checkbox.attr("checked"))
                checkbox.parent().addClass("multiselect-on");
            else
                checkbox.parent().removeClass("multiselect-on");
        });
    });
});
};

$(function() {
 $(".multiselect").multiselect();
});


</script>


<style>

label
{
line-height:25px;
}

 </style>




 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body><div class="multiselect">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="1"  class="styled" />Green</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="2"  class="styled"/>Red</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="3"  class="styled"/>Blue</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="4"  class="styled"/>Orange</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="5"  class="styled"/>Purple</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="6"  class="styled"/>Black</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="7"  class="styled"/>White</label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

custom-form-elements.js

```
                var checkboxHeight = "25";
            var radioHeight = "25";
            var selectWidth = "190";


            /* No need to change anything after this */


            document.write('<style type="text/css">input.styled { display: none; } select.styled { position: relative; width: ' + selectWidth + 'px; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); z-index: 5; } .disabled { opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50); }</style>');

            var Custom = {
                init: function() {
                    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"), span = Array(), textnode, option, active;
                    for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
                        if((inputs[a].type == "checkbox" || inputs[a].type == "radio") && inputs[a].className.indexOf("styled") > -1) {
                            span[a] = document.createElement("span");
                            span[a].className = inputs[a].type;

                            if(inputs[a].checked == true) {
                                if(inputs[a].type == "checkbox") {
                                    position = "0 -" + (checkboxHeight*2) + "px";
                                    span[a].style.backgroundPosition = position;
                                } else {
                                    position = "0 -" + (radioHeight*2) + "px";
                                    span[a].style.backgroundPosition = position;
                                }
                            }
                            inputs[a].parentNode.insertBefore(span[a], inputs[a]);
                            inputs[a].onchange = Custom.clear;
                            if(!inputs[a].getAttribute("disabled")) {
                                span[a].onmousedown = Custom.pushed;
                                span[a].onmouseup = Custom.check;
                            } else {
                                span[a].className = span[a].className += " disabled";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
                    for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
                        if(inputs[a].className.indexOf("styled") > -1) {
                            option = inputs[a].getElementsByTagName("option");
                            active = option[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                            textnode = document.createTextNode(active);
                            for(b = 0; b < option.length; b++) {
                                if(option[b].selected == true) {
                                    textnode = document.createTextNode(option[b].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                                }
                            }
                            span[a] = document.createElement("span");
                            span[a].className = "select";
                            span[a].id = "select" + inputs[a].name;
                            span[a].appendChild(textnode);
                            inputs[a].parentNode.insertBefore(span[a], inputs[a]);
                            if(!inputs[a].getAttribute("disabled")) {
                                inputs[a].onchange = Custom.choose;
                            } else {
                                inputs[a].previousSibling.className = inputs[a].previousSibling.className += " disabled";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    document.onmouseup = Custom.clear;
                },
                pushed: function() {
                    element = this.nextSibling;
                    if(element.checked == true && element.type == "checkbox") {
                        this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight*3 + "px";
                    } else if(element.checked == true && element.type == "radio") {
                        this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight*3 + "px";
                    } else if(element.checked != true && element.type == "checkbox") {
                        this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight + "px";
                    } else {
                        this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight + "px";
                    }
                },
                check: function() {
                    element = this.nextSibling;
                    if(element.checked == true && element.type == "checkbox") {
                        this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
                        element.checked = false;
                    } else {
                        if(element.type == "checkbox") {
                            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight*2 + "px";
                        } else {
                            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight*2 + "px";
                            group = this.nextSibling.name;
                            inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                            for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
                                if(inputs[a].name == group && inputs[a] != this.nextSibling) {
                                    inputs[a].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        element.checked = true;
                    }
                },
                clear: function() {
                    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                    for(var b = 0; b < inputs.length; b++) {
                        if(inputs[b].type == "checkbox" && inputs[b].checked == true && inputs[b].className.indexOf("styled") > -1) {
                            inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight*2 + "px";
                        } else if(inputs[b].type == "checkbox" && inputs[b].className.indexOf("styled") > -1) {
                            inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
                        } else if(inputs[b].type == "radio" && inputs[b].checked == true && inputs[b].className.indexOf("styled") > -1) {
                            inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight*2 + "px";
                        } else if(inputs[b].type == "radio" && inputs[b].className.indexOf("styled") > -1) {
                            inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
                        }
                    }
                },
                choose: function() {
                    option = this.getElementsByTagName("option");
                    for(d = 0; d < option.length; d++) {
                        if(option[d].selected == true) {
                            document.getElementById("select" + this.name).childNodes[0].nodeValue = option[d].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            window.onload = Custom.init;
```

Comment: NO, this is for windows, apache...

Comment: what must ı do?.. ı can not understand you?

Answer (score 0):

please try this.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style>
<script>
jQuery.fn.multiselect = function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
        var checkboxes = $(this).find("input:checkbox");
        checkboxes.each(function() {
            var checkbox = $(this);
            // Highlight pre-selected checkboxes
            if (checkbox.attr("checked"))
                checkbox.parent().addClass("multiselect-on");

            // Highlight checkboxes that the user selects
            checkbox.click(function() {
                if (checkbox.attr("checked"))
                    checkbox.parent().addClass("multiselect-on");
                else
                    checkbox.parent().removeClass("multiselect-on");
            });
        });
    });
};

$(function() {
     $(".multiselect").multiselect();
});


</script>

label
    {
    line-height:25px;
    }

</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.multiselect {
    width:10em;
    height:5em;
    border:solid 1px #c0c0c0;
    overflow:auto;
}

.multiselect label {
    display:block;
}

.multiselect-on {
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#3399ff;
}
</style>
<body><div class="multiselect">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="1"  class="styled" />Green</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="2"  class="styled"/>Red</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="3"  class="styled"/>Blue</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="4"  class="styled"/>Orange</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="5"  class="styled"/>Purple</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="6"  class="styled"/>Black</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="7"  class="styled"/>White</label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://www.supereleman.com/test/3.html

as you seen above, your suggestion disrupted my script... So, your answer isn't my solution

Comment: will anybody help to me?